# Overlay multiple images onto a base image of same size using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

[image]
[image]
I have a set of 193 images(Img0, Img1, Img2,...Imgx) of the same size(40x40) which needs to be overlayed onto the first image in this(that is Img0). I tried different solutions available here but it's working only for overlaying 2 images. I want this to be done using OpenCV& C++. I am pasting the code below.

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    

    string arrOfimages[193];
    stringstream str;
    int a = 1;

    for (int index = 0; index < 193 ; index++)
    {
        str << "C:/<path>/Img" << a << ".bmp";
        arrOfimages[index] = str.str();
        str.str("");
        a++;
    }

    Mat src1;
    Mat srcOut;
    src1 = imread(arrOfimages[0]);
    imshow("base", src1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 193; i++)
    {
        addWeighted(src1, 0.5, imread(arrOfimages[i+1]), 0.5, 0.0, srcOut, -1);
    }

    imshow("summation", srcOut);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}

    }
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

I am getting out of memory errors, assertion failed etc.

Comment: dont use magic numbers. Out-of-bounds is much easier to spot when it is not that magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 193; i++)
{
    addWeighted(src1, 0.5, imread(arrOfimages[i+1]), 0.5, 0.0, srcOut, -1);
}
```

You are adding +1 to the i which at the end will be 193 and out of bounds. You should just use int i=1 instead, like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 193; i++)
{
    addWeighted(src1, 0.5, imread(arrOfimages[i]), 0.5, 0.0, srcOut, -1);
}
```

Also, you add src1 and a new image and copy the output to srcOut... And in the next iteration you do it but with a next image, at the end you will have in srcOut only the result of adding the first and the last image. If you want to overlay all of them it should be something more like:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 193; i++)
{
    addWeighted(src1, 0.5, imread(arrOfimages[i]), 0.5, 0.0, srcOut, -1);
    src1 = srcOut;
}
```

---

Just as a note, the previous loop:

```
stringstream str;
int a = 1;

for (int index = 0; index < 193 ; index++)
{
    str << "C:/<path>/KCF" << a << ".bmp";
    arrOfimages[index] = str.str();
    str.str("");
    a++;
}
```

can be written like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 193 ; index++)
{
    stringstream str;
    str << R"(C:\<path>\KCF)" << (a+1) << ".bmp";
    arrOfimages[index] = str.str();
}
```

---

## Update:

You would like to have is a blended image that preserves the black spots. To do that you can use [bitwise_and](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) from opencv like this:

```
cv::Mat srcOut = cv::imread(arrOfImages[0], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
for(int i = 1; i < 193; i++)
{
    cv::bitwise_and(srcOut, cv::imread(arrOfImages[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), srcOut)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your quick response. I corrected the code, but I am getting the error like this :

Comment: OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file D:\OpenCV\OpenCV_3.4\opencv-3.4.1\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 356

Comment: @mira That means one of the images does not exist or it failed to load it. Does it give you that one in base? `imshow("base", src1);` ?  is `arrOfimages[0]` path correct?

Comment: Thanks once again and now the code works fine. I had to make a few changes in the path and iteration. You are the best :) Also, I would like to ask a doubt regarding the alpha and beta value. For getting an overlayed images of these 194 pictures, what is the ideal value of alpha and beta should be?

Comment: @mira that depends on what you want to achieve :) 0.5 is more or less like a blending, like making both semitransparent. So every iteration the first image will be more transparent and the new one less. You maybe want to add all with a constant value in a CV_32F cv::Mat so that it keeps the numbers (and then you cast it to CV_8U) or if you want both solid, you can try creating a mask for each image and then add both image with the mask. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) you can find a more detailed explanation of what I mean with transparent

Comment: Hi, after the final image is obtained, (I did the operation for inverted (negative)images. ) there is some grayscale present in the final image. What i meant is, the final image is not so sharp. There is a black point in the image and it gets fade out when I overlay the other images( it also has that black point , but slightly shifted up or down). Is there any way to get it as I mentioned???All the images I am using looks same, just slight movement of few points.

Comment: @mira it depends on the images, I think you should post with sample images to understand better what you want to do. But most probably you want to do something like bitwise And as described in the link I gave you before

Comment: I have added 2 pictures in my original question. It is showing failed to upload pics when I am trying to add more. I hope I can explain what I want with these 2 pictures. When I am using the addweighted function(blending), the black spots in the second image gets fade out. I have a set of these pictures, say around 200. So, when these pictures are blended together I am losing the black spots. I want a final picture in which all the black marks in all the pictures that have been used to be visible. Is this possible? If so, what changes should I make?

Comment: @mira it is possible, if the images are binary (0 and 255) you can use bitwise and. if one pixel is black (0) and the same one in the other image is white (255) this will give 0 as result. If both are white it will give a white pixel, and if both are black it will give you black, let me update the answer.